# Properly set up exponential decay of learning rate in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, learning-rate

I need to apply an exponential decay of learning rate every 10 epochs. Initial learning rate is `0.000001`, and decay factor is `0.95`

is this the proper way to set it up?

```
lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
        initial_learning_rate=0.000001, 
        decay_steps=(my_steps_per_epoch*10), 
        decay_rate=0.05)
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=lr_schedule, momentum=0.9)
```

The formula of exponential decay is `current_lr = initial_lr * (1 - decay_factor)^t`
Except that in [the code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/training/learning_rate_decay.py) it is implemented as :

```
decayed_learning_rate = learning_rate *
                      decay_rate ^ (global_step / decay_steps)
```

To my knowledge, `decay_rate` should be `1 - decay_factor` and `decay_steps` should mean how many steps are performed before applying the decay, in my case `my_steps_per_epoch*10`. Is that correct?

**EDIT:**

If I pause and save my model (using callbacks) after the 10th epoch, and then resume by loading the model and calling `model.fit` with `initial_epoch=10` and `epochs=11`, will it start in the 11th epoch and apply the exponential decay?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`decay_steps` can be used to state after how many steps (processed batches) you will decay the learning rate. I find it quite useful to just specify the initial and the final learning rate and calculate the decay_factor automatically via the following:

```
initial_learning_rate = 0.1
final_learning_rate = 0.0001
learning_rate_decay_factor = (final_learning_rate / initial_learning_rate)**(1/epochs)
steps_per_epoch = int(train_size/batch_size)

lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
                initial_learning_rate=initial_learning_rate,
                decay_steps=steps_per_epoch,
                decay_rate=learning_rate_decay_factor,
                staircase=True)
```